# Java Springboot: Return only some attributs of an object

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Assuming the following class:

```java
public class Foo {
  String a, b, c, d;

  // The rest of the class...
}
```

And a REST API controller using Springboot:

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
public Foo myFuntion() {
    return new Foo(...);
}
```

Requesting `/foo` return this JSON:

```
{
 "a": "...",
 "b": "...",
 "c": "...",
 "d": "..."
}
```

However, I would like to return only some attributes of the `Foo` class, for example, only attributes `a` and `b`.

How could I do that without creating a new class?

Comment: The idiomatic approach to solving this problem is to create DTO (Data transfer objects). Java doesn't much like "sometimes these values, sometimes not" since it makes for inconsistent APIs and breaks strong typing.

Comment: @Christopher Would that change if I always want to return only a and b?

Comment: In your existing DTO class, annotate that class with "@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)" and then set the attributes to null from foo before returning.

Comment: You could have a look at GraphQL where you'd be able to define what exactly should be returned.

Comment: If you never want to return a given property use `@JsonIgnore` on it. If you need to return different sets of properties in different places use `DTO`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two solutions

> **Use @JsonIgnore on the property you want to exclude**

For example, You want to exclude **a** from serializing.(Just want to get **b,c,d**)

```
public class TestDto {

@JsonIgnore
String a;
String b;
String c;
String d;
//Getter and Setter
}
```

> **Use @JsonInclude and @JsonIgnoreProperties**

Via this solution, if each of a,b,c,d is null, it will be excluded from the response.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TestDto {


String a;
String b;
String c;
String d;

//getters and setter

}
```

**[More information about Jackson annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)**

Answer (score 4):

You have plenty of options

1. Use dedicated DTO - separate class that contains only props you need
2. Use @JsonIgnore
3. Use @JsonView

... and there are many more. I personally am very comfortable with 3rd option
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation - but most straight forward and implementation independent is option 1 - so you can go for it as well.

Answer (score 2):

@JsonView will be the best option to handle all attributes in controlled way.

Define a view

```
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }

    public static class private {
    }
}
```

Map attributes

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
public String a;
```

And mark the return view

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
@RequestMapping("/items/{id}")
public Item getItemPublic(@PathVariable int id) {
    return ItemManager.getById(id);
}
```

Now all attributes marked with the view name will be returned.